# How to compare two strings based on date-time in perl & php?

Tags: php, perl

I have strings in the (date-time) format- "Mon, 11 Jul 2011 11:45:07 +08:00", I need to compare such strings based on the date-time format, for finding most recent string. Which module/method should i used here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw();

my $time_str = 'Mon, 11 Jul 2011 11:45:07 +08:00';
# your notation of time zone
# does not comply with relevant standards
$time_str    =~ s/([+-]\d\d):(\d\d) \z/$1$2/msx; # kill colon

my $parser   = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern  => '%a, %d %b %Y %T %z',
    locale   => 'en',   # 'Mon', 'Jul' are English
    on_error => 'croak',
);

my $datetime = $parser->parse_datetime($time_str);

# Now you have a DateTime object. To compare,
# use the overloaded relation operators.
# <=> operator/sort function works as well.

if ($datetime < $a_different_datetime) {
    say 'earlier';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For PHP, the easiest way would be converting the time strings with strtotime() and comparing the integer values. Highest integer is the latest.

Note that some versions of PHP will warn you when using Date functions if you have not set your default timezone. You can do so with `date_default_timezone_set("")` or php.ini's `date.timezone = ""`, with the [list of supported timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Comment: -1 for speculative answer. Trying out on 5.3.5 bombs out with warning message `It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. […]` etc. etc. There's more code needed to handle the time zone parsing, which you do not show. I don't think this is actually covered by the PHP standard library.

Comment: That warning just explains that it's using the default timezone setting for its date conversions. That has little to do with the conversion in question, because the timezone is explicitly given in the string. Why would the system's timezone matter if you give it as input? I guess you'll have to ask your fabled PHP 5.3.5 that. My PHP likely has the setting configured as part of its configuration, like all proper PHP installs should. There's nothing speculative in my answer, except assuming people actually configure their PHP installs.

Comment: Alright, that nullifies my critique. Edit your answer so I can change my vote; perhaps add a code sample and change the conjunctive mode?

Answer (score 1):

I use [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.24/lib/Date/Manip.pod) in Perl for this:

```
use Date::Manip;

my $datestr1 = "Mon, 11 Jul 2011 11:45:07 +08:00";
my $datestr2 = "Mon, 18 Jul 2011 11:45:07 +08:00";

my $date1 = new Date::Manip::Date;
my $date2 = $date1->new_date;
$date1->parse($datestr1);
$date2->parse($datestr2);

my $result = $date1->cmp($date2); # => -1, 0, 1

print $result, "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP it's called [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can try strtotime() on the timestamp you have. then just compare the numbers using normal comparators.